# React Native - keyboard visible-password android doesn't show numbers

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

I want the same keyboard password for a normal input

`keyboardType="visible-password"` only works in android, and that is ok to me, but when I try to apply this keyboard to a normal input, it doesn´t show the keyboard I want, with numbers at the top. Here what I wish:

[image: keyboard]

Here what I get:

[image: bad keyboard]

And here some code. Thank you if you can help me

```
<TextInput
        text={getRutInputValue(text)}
        label={label}
        textValid={isCheckRut}
        textError={textError}
        maxLength={RUT_MAX_LENGTH}
        onChangeTextValid={onChangeTextValid}
        onChangeText={setRutInputValue}
        keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'visible-password' : 'numbers-and-punctuation'}
        autoComplete="off"
        accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
    />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `visible-password` type only works when the input has the secureTextEntry flag.

[image]

Check the guide https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/ recomended by the react-native documentation.

Comment: In multiple apps, I am using this code to hide and show password and hide suggestions when the password is visible.

`secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
  keyboardType={hidePassword ? undefined : 'visible-password'}`

Now as per the docs, visible-password can only be used with secureTextEntry which probably shows why this code doesn't work in my current project, but then, why does it work in my other projects (have been using the same in multiple apps)

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextInput
    text={getRutInputValue(text)}
    label={label}
    textValid={isCheckRut}
    textError={textError}
    maxLength={RUT_MAX_LENGTH}
    onChangeTextValid={onChangeTextValid}
    onChangeText={setRutInputValue}
    secureTextEntry={this.state.password}
    keyboardType={Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'visible-password' : 'numbers-and-punctuation'}
    autoComplete="off"
    accessibilityLabel={accessibilityLabel}
/>
```

Above code worked for me. Here I am setting `this.state.password` on change.
In documentation of react-native it has mentioned that to get visible-password we need to set `secureTextEntry` in the TextInput.

Sharing my reference link as well : https://mdmoin07.medium.com/react-native-hide-show-password-input-d4be4d0f70aa